# Join two Dataframe without a common field in Spark-scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join

I have two dataframes in Spark Scala, but one of these is composed by a unique column. I have to join them but they have no column in common. The number of row is the same.

```
val userFriends=userJson.select($"friends",$"user_id") 
val x = userFriends("friends")
        .rdd
        .map(x => x.getList(0).toArray.map(_.toString)) 
val y = x.map(z=>z.count(z=>true)).toDF("friendCount")
```

I have to join userFriends with y

Comment: What is the question ? What have you done so far ?

Comment: val userFriends=userJson.select($"friends",$"user_id")

val x = userFriends("friends").rdd.map(x => x.getList(0).toArray.map(_.toString))

val y= x.map(z=>z.count(z=>true)).toDF("friendCount")     

i have to join userFriends with y

Comment: @mastMarvizz Welcome to SO. I've added the code to the question. Follow the example next time :-)

Comment: sorry and thank you, it's my first question :)

Comment: I think it would help if you add a data sample to the question as well. How is `userJson` looking like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to join them without common fields, except if you can rely on a ordering, in this case you can use row-number (with window-function) on both dataframes and join on the row-number.

But in your case this does not seem necessary, just keep the `user_id` column in your dataframe, something like this should work:

```
val userFriends=userJson.select($"friends",$"user_id")

val result_df = 
  userFriends.select($"friends",$"user_id")
  .rdd
  .map(x => (x.getList(0).toArray.map(_.toString).count(z=>true)),x.getInt(1)))
  .toDF("friendsCount","user_id")
```